# Automate Screenshots for IOS

Tags: ios, ios5, automation, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to build a tool that downloads an app from the market or App Store and run it on a device and take screenshots.

I have been successful in doing this on android devices by using monkey runner tool.

Is the same possible for iOS?

Comment: If you are going to submit to the app store, then no. Jailbroken devices might be possible.

Comment: @danielbeard: no no, i am trying to download apps on istore to the device connected to the laptop via some program and then run them and take screenshots. The programs m downloading are random (those are not my apps). I want to automate the whole process by giving the app name as the input to the tool

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 4.0 you can use UIAutomation to obtain this.

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html#tools